# DataGridViewImageColumn red x

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I've created a DataGridView and added a DataGridViewImageColumn (using the Designer).

The DataGridView has "AllowUserToAddRows = true" so a blank row is displayed for the user to enter a new row in. In this blank row the DataGridViewImageColumn displays a red x. I want to always display the same image in the column regardless of whether the row has any data or not (I am binding the cell's click event so using the DataGridViewImageColumn as a button).

How do I get rid of the red x?

Comment: If a row has no data, why is it displayed/visible ?

Comment: Cerebrus, a blank row is displayed because the "AllowUserToAddRows = true". I have edited my question to include this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use an ImageList to hold all my images, but here's a trimmed down version that should help. You're right to set the Value, but you should set it to the null-equivalent of a bitmap, which is just a static blank image. I use:

```
e.Value = (imageIndex != int.MinValue) ? imageList.Images[imageIndex] : nullImage;
```

where nullImage is defined earlier in the class as:

```
private readonly Image nullImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked through these solutions and the way I got this to work was to do this after `InitializeComponent()` call in the constructor to make the default image for data bound rows an empty image

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
```

And hook the `RowPrePaintEvent` to remove the red X for the empty row at the end of the grid because `AllowUserToAddRows = true`:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.RowIndex >= numberOfRows)
      {
           dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = null;
      }
}
```

Where `numberOfRows` is the number of valid rows in the grid. Just spent a few hours dealing with this. Hope this saves someone else the headache...

Answer (score 2):

I used IsNewRow property of grid.row like this

```
private void dgUserFileList_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e) {
      DataGridViewRow row = dgUserFileList.Rows[e.RowIndex];
      if (row.IsNewRow) {
          row.Cells[0].Value = null;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, but I'm not sure it's the best way.

I override the RowsAdded event and set the Value of the DataGridViewImageColumn to null. I think since the value is null, it displays the image.

```
private void dgvWorksheet_RowsAdded(object sender, 
     DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    dgvWorksheet.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[colStartClock.Index].Value = null;
}
```

I also set the NullValue of the Column to null in the Form_Load

```
colStartClock.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
```

I'm not sure if there's anything else I need to do. It seems to be working but it seems a bit buggy - random clicking sometimes results in exceptions, so more investigation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) is rather verbose on this:

> By default, empty cells display a default error graphic. To prevent
>   this graphic from appearing for cell values equal to **null** or
>   [DBNull.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx), set the [DataGridViewCellStyle.NullValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.nullvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the
>   cell style object returned by the [DefaultCellStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property to **null**
>   before adding rows to the control. This does not affect the row for
>   new records, however. To prevent the error graphic from appearing in
>   the row for new records when the control [AllowUserToAddRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) property
>   value is **true**, you must also either explicitly set the cell value to
>   **null** in a handler for the control [RowsAdded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx) event or set the column
>   [CellTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) property to an instance of a
>   [DataGridViewImageCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecell(v=vs.110).aspx)-derived type with an overridden
>   [DefaultNewRowValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecell.defaultnewrowvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property that returns **null**.

Translated to code it means you can do this before adding any rows:

```
var column = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
column.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewEmptyImageCell();
```

And then put this class somewhere:

```
private class DataGridViewEmptyImageCell : DataGridViewImageCell
{
    public override object DefaultNewRowValue { get { return null; } }
}
```

Or set `Cell.Value` to null in the `Rows.Added` event.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid this default behavior for all the DataGridViewImageColumn elements in a DataGridView is to intercept the CellFormatting event:

```
dataGridView1.CellFormatting += delegate(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;

    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewImageColumn &&
        grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].DefaultNewRowValue.Equals(e.Value))
        e.Value = null;
};
```

This way the component will always use the NullValue image for the cell instead of the default "unavailable image".